# Discord.js Bot Custom Status (Listening, Watching, etc.)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm just trying to figure out why the code for my Discord bot's custom status isn't working.

````
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",
        game: {
            name: ">help",
            type: "LISTENING"
        }
    });
 });```
````

Comment: how do you know it isn't working? and how are we to verify what is happening with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I researched on Discord.js Documentation, **there's [no parameter](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceData) on [setPresence() method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence) called *game* but there's one called *activity*, which you might use.**

In this method, you can set the [status](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceStatusData), activity name, and its [type](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType) (like listening or playing), all in once; compared to [setActivity()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) and [setStatus()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setStatus) methods, since it's a combination of both.

**Therefore, you better write this code, if you want to use setPresence method:**

```
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
client.user.setPresence({
   status: "online",
   activity: {
      name: ">help",
      type: "LISTENING"
   }
});
```

I hope this could help!

Comment: This answer is correct, please mark it as so @AnkieTankie